# jQuery - Show first div as default on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<!-- Unordered list - navigation -->
<ul id="linkwrapper">
   <li><a id="link1" href="#">link1</a></li>
   <li><a id="link2" href="#">link2</a></li>
   <li><a id="link3" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Hidden Elements-->
<div id="infocontent">
   <div id="link1content">Information about 1.</div>
   <div id="link2content">Information about 2.</div>
   <div id="link3content">Information about 3.</div>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div').hide(); // Hide All Content Divs

$('#linkwrapper a').click(function(){
    var $contentDiv = $("#" + this.id + "content");

    if($contentDiv.is(":visible")) {
        $contentDiv.hide(); // Hide Div
    } else {            
        $allContentDivs.hide(); // Hide All Divs
        $contentDiv.show(); // Show Div
    }

    return false;        
  });
});
```

When add about code to load in page. i want to show up first link already click as load the script.
It means "Information about 1." visible in page load.
how can i do it.

Example here
[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sXqnD/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Updated your JSfiddle. Check that. You can do this without JQuery too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div') // Hide All Content Divs

$('#linkwrapper li a').click(function(){
    var $contentDiv = $("#" + this.id + "content");

    if($contentDiv.is(":visible")) {
        $contentDiv.hide(); // Hide Div
    } else {            
        $allContentDivs.hide(); // Hide All Divs
        $contentDiv.show(); // Show Div
    }

    return false;        
  });
});
```

Your CSS

```
.hide{
   display:none;
}
 .show{
  display:inline
}
```

Your HTML:

```
 <!-- Unordered list - navigation -->

 <ul id="linkwrapper">
    <li><a id="link1" class="show" href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li><a id="link2"  href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a id="link3"  href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

 <!-- Hidden Elements-->
 <div id="infocontent">
   <div id="link1content" class="show">Information about 1.</div>
   <div id="link2content" class="hide">Information about 2.</div>
   <div id="link3content" class="hide">Information about 3.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by updating your selector

```
   var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

and initiating again the $allContentDivs inside your click event

```
$allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : hide all dive except first using following code

```
$('#infocontent div:not(:first)').hide();//hide all but first
var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div');//get all divs
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/sXqnD/577/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add .not(':first') like:

```
var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div').not(':first').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div').hide();

$( "#infocontent div" ).first().show();
```

Comment: But i want to hide first link when click 2nd or 3rd link. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about you show the first div after hiding all?

Like this:

```
$('#infocontent div').first().show();
```

Comment: But i want to hide  first link when click 2nd or 3rd link.
Any ideas?

Comment: When i click same link twice, that's text vanishing.. how can i solve it ?

Comment: Well, this:
'if($contentDiv.is(":visible")) {
        $contentDiv.hide(); // Hide Div
}'

hides the div. Aren't you trying to achieve that?
Or don't you want that for the first div?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sXqnD/568/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $allContentDivs = $('#infocontent div').hide(); // Hide All Content Divs

    $('#linkwrapper a').click(function(){
        var $contentDiv = $("#" + this.id + "content");

        if($contentDiv.is(":visible")) {
            $contentDiv.hide(); // Hide Div
        } else {            
            $allContentDivs.hide(); // Hide All Divs
            $contentDiv.show(); // Show Div
        }

        return false;        
    });

    $('#linkwrapper a').eq(0).click();//manually click the first anchor using .eq()
});
```

Hide everything and have a manual click on the first link so that it will show